# Hovering Texts and bottoms

Tags: hover, mousehover

I am having a problem with my theme navigation bar , when there is only one word like home or contact and you take the mouse on it hover the world in the right way but when i add a word to it like home page the hover shows the second word below the main one as well and doesn't function properly.
here is the HTML code:

```
    <li>
    <a href="#" data-hover="ABOUT US" >ABOUT US</a> </li>
```

here is the CSS Script:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .menu > li > a::before,
    .menu .current > a::before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 0;
        color: rgb(34,171,166);
        content: attr(data-hover);
        -webkit-transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
        transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
    }
    .menu > li > a:hover::before,
    .menu > li > a:focus::before,
    .menu > .active > a {
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
        transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put you code in the text and not in an image.

Comment: <li>
         <a href="#" data-hover="ABOUT US">ABOUT US</a>

        </li>

Comment: @media (min-width:768px) {
  .menu > li > a::before,
  .menu .current > a::before {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   left: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 0;
   color: rgb(34,171,166);
   content: attr(data-hover);
   -webkit-transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
   transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
  }
  .menu > li > a:hover::before,
  .menu > li > a:focus::before,
  .menu > .active > a {
   max-width: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
   transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
  }
 }

Comment: You should edit your question and include it there. Using 4 spaces before a line will make it into a code block...

Comment: hmmm. You original code hade `ABOUT&nbsp;US` in it. setting `data-hover` to the same might answer your question...

Comment: Please mark the answer as the 'accepted' answer...

Answer (score 1):

So, as described in the comments: You original code had:

```
<a href="#" data-hover="ABOUT US" >ABOUT&nbsp;US</a> </li>
```

As you can see: a non-breaking space prevents the original text to get broken up in two lines. The `data-hover` does not have this breaking space, hence it behaves differently.

You could also add `white-space: nowrap;`, so you don't need to insert the non-breaking spaces manually.